# Is using Git GUI's professional practice?

Tags: git

I aspire to work at a creative agency one day, so I've been preparing myself by learning professional development workflow instead of 'cowboy coding.'

Is it considered amateur to use GUI for git?  Will an employer be turned off by that?  Should I just keep learning to navigate through git using Terminal for best practice?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I know lots of good developers that only interact with version control software using some sort of GUI. Do they get the full range of features of the VCS that way? Probably not. But you can still perform all important tasks with it. And for Git, there are quite some GUIs that are really powerful (in terms of covering the features available from the command line).

Comment: I think this is heavily based on one's opinion. I for myself would consider anyone amateur who does *not* take advantage of a good GUI, just because it does not feel "hardcore" enough.

Comment: Wait... there *is* a GUI for Git? All this time, and I had no idea ;)

Comment: It's actually an interesting question. I personally use both for different purposes. If you're going to use the command-line, set up your shell properly to display the current branch, and check out the invaluable `tig`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is way better to use a git GUI proficiently then to use the command-line poorly. An employer should definitely appreciate that!

I've seen several times where people want to use the command-line to prove their chops, but are breaking stuff all over and by doing so only proved that they are stubborn and not practical developers. Being pragmatic is absolutely desirable.

At my workplace most people (including me) are using [source tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).  You can even turn on a "verbose" mode to see what commands are being triggered.  The preference is "Always display full console output".

Good luck!